# How do i know when a button is clicked through the viewmodel in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin

I'm very bad at Xamarin and need help, the title explains itself, I really need to detect a button click in the **ViewModel** from the view, how do I do this?
My code is non-existent so... yeah. Please help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Bind a Command To the button.

```
 <Button Text="Button"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}" />
```

In Your ViewModel

```
public Command ButtonCommand { set; get; } 

public ConstructorViewModel()
{
    
    ButtonCommand = new Command(ShowAlert);
}


private async void ShowAlert(object obj)
{
    // Do whatever functionality you want
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by _page? can you please elaborate? ( sorry if the question is stupid)

Comment: You dont need it. you can simply avoid it.